# How to use non-anonymous methods in Eloquent subqueries?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, anonymous-function

In eloquent we can using anonymous functions as second parameter in where method. i want to use a non-anonymous class method instead of it. but doesn't work for me.

**regular anonymous mode:** (working old style) - I don't want to use this method

```
           ->whereIn('plantation_id', function ($query) use ($plantationId){
          $query->select('id')
          ->from('plantations')
          ->whereBetween('_lft', [
              DB::raw('(SELECT `_lft` FROM `plantations` WHERE id = ' . $plantationId .')'),
              DB::raw('(SELECT `_rgt` FROM `plantations` WHERE id = '. $plantationId .')')
              ]);

       });
```

**I want to use:**

Query:

```
 ->whereIn('plantation_id', Plantation::getIdsByParent($query, $plantationId));
```

Plantation Class:

```
class Plantation extends Model
{
 ....
     public static function getIdsByParent($query, $plantationId)
    {
        return $query->select('id')
            ->from('plantations')
            ->whereBetween('_lft', [
                DB::raw('(SELECT `_lft` FROM `plantations` WHERE id = ' . $plantationId .')'),
                DB::raw('(SELECT `_rgt` FROM `plantations` WHERE id = '. $plantationId .')')
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could define a relation between the two models instead, then be like `Model::all()->plantations()->...` - this is probably the best way to go about achieving it. Relations between modals is very handy!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to duplicate code you can do:

```php
->whereIn('plantation_id', function($query) use ($plantationId) {
    return Plantation::getIdsByParent($query, $plantationId);
});
```

Still has an anonymous function but you are making use of your already defined logic without copy-pasting it.

Comment: Yes, that will definitely work with this. But there must be a way to use directly without the use of anonymous function.

Comment: There is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error you get?

As far as i understand it you want to get a Collection/Array of id's with your getIdsByParent.

My understanding would be you that your function returns a QueryBuilder instance to return a collection you would need to add a ->get() at the end. Does this work for you:

```
     public static function getIdsByParent($query, $plantationId)
    {
        return $query->select('id')
            ->from('plantations')
            ->whereBetween('_lft', [
                DB::raw('(SELECT `_lft` FROM `plantations` WHERE id = ' . $plantationId .')'),
                DB::raw('(SELECT `_rgt` FROM `plantations` WHERE id = '. $plantationId .')')
            ])->get();
    }
```

If you want to have an array a simple ->toArray() at the end should do.

Also maybe using a Query Scope for this does the trick.

[Laravel Docs Query Socpes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: No. it should to be run as a sub Query. this method will be run an other query